# Prod routes require `app.php`

Tags: php, symfony, ubuntu, mod-rewrite

All routes in prod environment except for `\` require including `app.php`. With `app.php` all site features are available. Dev environment behaves as expected. Environment is Ubuntu 12.04 (on Win 8 VirtualBox VM), PHP 5.4, Apache 2.2.  Typical Apache error log entry:

> [client 127.0.0.1] File does not exist:
>   /var/www/volunteer/web/non-profits

Some additional details:

- PHP 5.4.31-1+deb.sury.org~precise+1
- `.htaccess` exists in `...\web`
- `mod_rewrite` is enabled.
- Symfony 2.5.3 prod cache has been cleared (many, many times)
- assets installed
- assetic dumped
- vhost directory index includes `app.php`
- tried AllowOverride all

What have I missed?

#### Here's .htaccess (sans comments)

```
DirectoryIndex app.php

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}::$1 ^(/.+)/(.*)::\2$
    RewriteRule ^(.*) - [E=BASE:%1]

    RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
    RewriteRule ^app\.php(/(.*)|$) %{ENV:BASE}/$2 [R=301,L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
    RewriteRule .? - [L]

    RewriteRule .? %{ENV:BASE}/app.php [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_alias.c>
        RedirectMatch 302 ^/$ /app.php/
    </IfModule>
</IfModule>
```

#### a route:

```
$ php app/console router:debug --env=prod
[router] Current routes
 Name                              Method   Scheme Host Path                      
...
 nonprofits                        ANY      ANY    ANY  /non-profits
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question I should have asked was, "Why was Apache ignoring .htaccess?"  The answer was found in the [Ubuntu forums here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1506129). Using webmin, I changed the `AllowOverride` directive so it now reads:

```
<Directory /var/www/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
</Directory>
```

This was just a level up from where I'd been looking.

Answer (score 1):

Do you know if Apache is executing what's in .htaccess? Maybe you need AllowOverride all?

Comment: Another nice thought.  Tried that, too.  I'll add that to my question.

Comment: Turns out you were right, just not where I thought you were talking about.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you forgot to install the assets ?

Try to type in your terminal:

- php app/console assets:install --env=production
- php app/console assetic:dump --env=production

Obviously add the --env=production part if you are in production.

Make sure to have the following line in your vhost as well:

> DirectoryIndex app.php

Comment: Nice thought, but already done.  I'll include those in my question.